# how can i push button change right parts with url change flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

[i make admin page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7NUu.png)

I am making an admin page. I want to change only the red screen on the right side when the left button is pressed. However, the url must be changed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SplashPageState();
}

class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    tabController = new TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
    tabController.addListener(() {
      if (tabController.indexIsChanging) setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(child: _portraitWidget(height, width)),
    );
  }

  Widget _portraitWidget(double height, double width) {
    return Container(
      height: height,
      width: width,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.white,
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            // padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            child: RotatedBox(
              quarterTurns: 1,
              child: TabBar(
                controller: tabController,
                indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
                indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                // labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                //     left: AppDimens.space40, right: AppDimens.space40),
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                isScrollable: true,
                tabs: <Widget>[
                  getItem(page: HomePagesEnum.PAGE_1, text: "PAGE_1"),
                  getItem(page: HomePagesEnum.PAGE_2, text: "PAGE_2"),
                  getItem(page: HomePagesEnum.PAGE_3, text: "PAGE_3"),
                  getItem(page: HomePagesEnum.PAGE_4, text: "PAGE_4"),
                  getItem(page: HomePagesEnum.PAGE_5, text: "PAGE_5"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              // padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(end: AppDimens.space32),
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: tabController,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: <Widget>[
                  _buildContent("Page 1", Colors.red),
                  _buildContent("Page 2", Colors.blue),
                  _buildContent("Page 3", Colors.blueAccent),
                  _buildContent("Page 4", Colors.amber),
                  _buildContent("Page 5", Colors.green),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent(String title, Color color) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("$title"),
      color: color,
    );
  }

  Widget getItem({required String text, required HomePagesEnum page}) {
    bool isSelected = (page.index == tabController.index);
    return RotatedBox(
      quarterTurns: -1,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: isSelected ? 18 : 15),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum HomePagesEnum { PAGE_1, PAGE_2, PAGE_3, PAGE_4, PAGE_5 }
```